# Fast byte copy C++11

Tags: c#, c++, linux, c++11, g++

I need to convert C# app which uses extensively bytes manipulation.

An example:

```
    public abstract class BinRecord
    {
        public static int version => 1;

        public virtual int LENGTH => 1 + 7 + 8 + 2 + 1; // 19

        public char type;
        public ulong timestamp; // 7 byte
        public double p;
        public ushort size;
        public char callbackType;

        public virtual void FillBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            bytes[0] = (byte)type;

            var t = BitConverter.GetBytes(timestamp);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(t, 0, bytes, 1, 7);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(p), 0, bytes, 8, 8);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(size), 0, bytes, 16, 2);
            bytes[18] = (byte)callbackType;
        }
    }
```

Basically `BitConverter` and `Buffer.BlockCopy` called 100s times per sec.

There are several classes that inherit from the base class above doing more specific tasks. For example:

```
    public class SpecRecord : BinRecord
    {
        public override int LENGTH => base.LENGTH + 2;
        public ushort num;

        public SpecRecord() { }
        public SpecRecord(ushort num)
        {
            this.num = num;
        }

        public override void FillBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var idx = base.LENGTH;
            base.FillBytes(bytes);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(num), 0, bytes, idx + 0, 2);
        }
    }
```

What approach in C++ should I look into?

Comment: probably `memcpy`

Comment: C++ is closer to the metal. Any object can be viewed as a byte array with a simple `reinterpret_cast`. Note that the reverse is not always true, and a byte array often requires help (alignment, endian conversion, etc...) to be viewed as an object. If you start with an X, convert it to bytes and then convert those bytes back to X, you're safe.

Comment: You may be able to write a more optimal copy than `memcpy`, by taking advantage of special processor instructions or helpful hardware (such as DMA). Also, loop unrolling.

Comment: the X is converted back on different machine by different software. so I just need to make sure the bytes are in as expected order, eg X -> bytes -> X is irrelevant here

Comment: @ThomasMatthews its not feasible for me to do (would take weeks, I need it in few days)

Comment: I'll write you a memcpy in less than 1hr.  I'm presently debugging that issue on an embedded system.  I don't see why using `memcpy` or writing your own would take weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option, in my opinion, is to actually go to C - use `memcpy` to copy over the bytes of any object.

Your above code would then be re-written as follows:

```
void FillBytes(uint8_t* bytes)
{
     bytes[0] = (uint8_t)type;
     memcpy((bytes + 1), &t, sizeof(uint64_t) - 1);
     memcpy((bytes + 8), &p, sizeof(double));
     memcpy((bytes + 16), &size, sizeof(uint16_t));
     bytes[18] = (uint8_t)callbackType;
}
```

Here, I use `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, and `uint64_t` as replacements for the `byte`, `ushort`, and `ulong` types.

Keep in mind, your timestamp copy is not portable to a big-endian CPU - it will  cut off the lowest byte rather than the highest. Solving that would require copying in each byte manually, like so:

```
//Copy a 7 byte timestamp into the buffer.
bytes[1] = (t >> 0) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (t >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytes[3] = (t >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[4] = (t >> 24) & 0xFF;
bytes[5] = (t >> 32) & 0xFF;
bytes[6] = (t >> 40) & 0xFF;
bytes[7] = (t >> 48) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: FYI, `memcpy` is also available in C++.

Comment: Sure, but the general advice I see for C++ programmers is to avoid messing directly with memory, which `memcpy` absolutely does. In C, this is the standard way to do this.

Comment: `&(((uint8_t*)(t))[1])` - errors with Segmentation fault

Comment: `&t` works though - as the *insignificant* byte is the last in the array so `memcpy(dst, &t, 7)` is the correct solution for my endianness at least.

Comment: Does your platform have strict alignment requirements?

Comment: Idk. I assume it is. How do I check? I am using VM on AMD x64 Windows host. Guest - CentOS9, g++ v 11

Comment: No, x86-64 doesn't have strict alignment requirements. I can see an error in the answer - my brain interpreted the timestamp as a pointer rather than an integer. I'll modify the answer.